# How to handle case when API response returns a null body in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am calling a File Server's REST API using POST method and sending it file content to be uploaded. The REST API should ideally save the file and send a response which contains fileName.
My code is something like this.

```
public String uploadFile() {
    UploadResponse response = restTemplate.postForObject(
            FILE_SERVER_URL/upload,
            new HttpEntity<>(fileContent, headers),
            UploadResponse.class);
    return response.getFileName();
}
```

In the above code, the compiler complains that `UploadResponse response` could be null, and I should handle that.
I plan to handle it with the below code.

```
public String uploadFile() {
    UploadResponse response = restTemplate.postForObject(
            FILE_SERVER_URL/upload,
            new HttpEntity<>(fileContent, headers),
            UploadResponse.class);
    if(response != null) {
            return response.getFileServiceId();
        }
        else {
            throw new RuntimeException("File upload failed");
        }
}
```

However, I am not sure if it is the right way to handle this. I don't feel this is a Runtime Exception. Please guide me as how should I handle the case that response could be null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Optional to avoid null checks in your code.

You can read this really insightful Q/A here - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/309134/why-is-using-an-optional-preferential-to-null-checking-the-variable